# DrawingML to SVG conversion?

Tags: svg, drawingml

Does anyone have any way to convert DrawingML markup into SVG?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but this [pptx to svg](http://www.dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j/browser/trunk/docx4j/src/pptx4j/java/org/pptx4j/convert/out/svginhtml/pptx2svginhtml.xslt) code seems to do that.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do exactly what I want, but the pointer to the docx4j project is something that I can work with that I hadn't previously found.

Thanks